# Why would I go to a checkpoint?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In systems with lockdown or war, you get "checkpoints" near some planets and stations. They show up on the navigation panel. I've tried stopping at a couple, and some ships from one local faction scan you, and nothing else seems to happen.

Is there a reason to go to a checkpoint ever? As it's so easy to just not go to a checkpoint, do they serve any purpose at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Checkpoints are an indicator that a system is in lockdown, and can be useful in destabilizing the faction controlling the checkpoint and potentially instigating a civil war**.

To cause civil war in a system, you must:

- Increase another factions influence such that its influence rivals the influence of the controlling faction
- Cause civil unrest in the controlling faction by attacking ships belonging to them (security, traders, miners, etc), accepting their missions but choosing alternate endings, or importing prohibited goods into stations controlled by them

As the level of civil unrest increases, it can trigger a state of lockdown for the controlling faction. This will cause them to create checkpoints that contain ships for the controlling faction. You can then use checkpoints as a place to conveniently kill security of the controlling faction to further create unrest, lower security levels, and spark a civil war.

There have been [reports](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=98450&p=1572868&viewfull=1#post1572868) of Type 9 vessels in checkpoints owned by the controlling faction that contain confiscated contraband (such as weapons). Some commanders have earned some credits by stealing the goods and selling them at the nearest black market.

Answer (score 1):

Checkpoints are practically the best place to farm Combat rank. A lot of Viper and Eagle ships with Master-Elite ranks. They are easy to kill and they spawn again and again. It's recommended to do it on an Anarchy system to avoid legal problems.

You can check this info in: https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Checkpoint